# Prove that rational points are countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that the set of points (p,q) on the plane - (where p,q are rational coordinates) is countable. I don't understand what I need to do to prove this

Answer (score 3):

The problem asks you to show that the set $\{\langle p,q\rangle\in\Bbb R^2\mid p,q\in\Bbb Q\}=\Bbb{Q\times Q}$ is countable.

To prove this, recall that $\Bbb Q$ is countable, and use the basic theorems about countable sets.

Comment: Dear Asaf - Moments ago came the message that moderator elections are upon us. If it's something you would consider, I would be delighted to nominate you - as I am sure many others would as well. Regrads,

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for the support. I am not personally cut for being a moderator on this website. I have declared that more than several times already that I will never, ever *ever* consider taking moderatorship on this website. But thanks for the vote of confidence.